# Wordpress error log does not show the location of a specific error

Tags: php, wordpress

The error log usually shows errors and their locations (filenames and line numbers) (or that's what I think). However, I get this error without any information on its location:

```
Aq_Resize.process() error: $width parameter is required
```

This happens with this error only (the locations of other errors are shown). I enabled `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` but it did not fix the issue.

Why is the location of this error is not shown? How can I know where it occurs to try to fix it?

Comment: Are you using any plugin to resize images?

Comment: There are many installed plugins that may use Aqua Resizer as a part of their work, that's why I wanted to trace back the error. It happens when a user with no manage_options capability tries to edit a page with WPBakey.

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/syamilmj/Aqua-Resizer/issues/83?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to see the error in the frontend of WordPress Site then you should check `apache error log` file.

Here all errors are stored.

> \apache\logs\error.log